# Integrating an Existing Express.js Backend with Next.js and Authentication Handling between Next.js and the Existing Backend

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js, mern

- How can I seamlessly integrate my current Express.js backend with Next.js while leveraging Next.js features such as server actions and file-based routing?
- I'm familiar with creating custom backends in Next.js, but given that I already have an established backend used for a mobile app, how can I utilize my existing Express.js backend within Next.js without recreating it?
- If I implement an auth.js module in Next.js for authentication, what would be the best approach to validate these requests in my existing backend system?
- Considering my existing backend handles authentication for multiple platforms, how can I ensure the authentication requests from Next.js are properly validated and processed within my current backend infrastructure?

Please if someone gives code or GitHub repo that would help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.